# Call System.Diagnostics.Process.Start from SQL CLR function that contain param with xml

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, clrstoredprocedure

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 CLR project. This function call a console application with a parameter that contain some xml.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure()]
public static SqlInt32 ExecuteApp(SqlString utilPath, SqlString arguments, ref SqlString result)  
{
    ProcessStartInfo info  = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
    Process p = new Process();

    try
    {
        //ProcessStartInfo to run the DOS command attrib

        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.RedirectStandardError = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c ""{0}"" {1}", utilPath, arguments);
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(info.Arguments);

        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();
        String processResults = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(processResults);
        result = processResults;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty((String)result))
            result = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        return 1;
    }
    finally
    {
        p.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem here with param that contain xml. 
This is a expression for execute stored procedure:

```
    declare @Result nvarchar(max)
exec ExecuteApp 'C:\Console.exe', 'send "<messages><message>my message</message></messages>"', @Result out 
select @Result
```

After executing stored procedure I have got an error like:

> < was unexpected at this time.

I want to noticed that without xml all is working properly.

Comment: You have _severe_ security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Why aren't you using `xp_cmdshell`?

Comment: xp_cmdshell needs to be enabled at a server level as well and then opens a whole new avenue for injection attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML contains special characters which are interpreted by the command shell (`>` and `<`).
You need to quote the parameter and escape quotes inside of it with `""`.

Also, you should execute your program directly (not through `cmd /c`); that will resolve some of your issues.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. But really execution string seems to be:

Comment: exec ExecuteApp 'C:\Console.exe', 'send "<messages><message>my message</messages></message>"', @Result out select @Result. So, with "<" symbols. So, that why console app response contain output "< was unexpected at this time"

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying.  Read my answer; it explains your problem.

Comment: Actually, I have not problem when I run from console : "C:\Console.exe" send "<messages><message>my message</messages></message>". So, is it really a problem with (> and <) or with ""?

Comment: Your quotes are being parsed by `cmd /c`.  You should start your program directly.  Also, that won't work with arbitrary XML.

Comment: Why aren't you using xp_cmdshell?

Comment: May be  you are right about xp_cmdshell. But how to transmit param with xml in this case?